# Python : 'break' outside loop Error in a While loop

Tags: python, loops

I've researched this problem but can't find a solution. As far as I know, my `break` statement is in my `while` loop, but I still get the Syntax error.

```
entered_number = 1

while entered_number >=0 :
    entered_number = int(input ("Number to add :"))
    sum += entered_number
    print("Entered number :",entered_number,"\nSum up til now:", sum)
else:
    print("The Final sum is :", sum)
    break
```

I know another solution to make my code work, but don't understand why this does not?

Thank you

Comment: Your 'break' statement is not inside the while loop. You can just remove it. When your program gets to the else, the loop is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I figured out that the `else` statement does not need `break` to get out of the loop...

Comment: `else` is not needed too. You can just print the final sum after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your break statement is not inside the loop. It’s in the scope of the else statement, but not in the scope of your while loop

Answer (score 0):

A `break` statement must be inside a loop. In your example, it isn't, it's in the `else` block (the fact that the `else` is associated with a loop is inconsequential.

Then again, the `else` clause will only be executed once, so there isn't much of a point to having a `break` statement there anyway. Just remove it and you should be OK.